# Fast pagination for millions of pages - how?

Tags: mysql, database, pagination

let's assume I am using MySQL and making a bookstore application which shows a paginated list of all available books (with hundred of millions of books in it)

```
db_table bookstore
    id = auto incremented primary key
    title = character field (indexed)
```

if I try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `db_table` ORDER BY `title` OFFSET 20.000.000 LIMIT 50
```

it will take too much time (probably way more than 10 seconds, which is too much already)

to reduce this time I am adjusting db table schema this way:

```
db_table bookstore
    ...
    alphabetically_sorted_title_number = integer field (indexed)
```

and then I can query pages like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `db_table` WHERE `alphabetically_sorted_title_number` > 20.000.000 ORDER BY `title` LIMIT 50
```

it will take less than 1 second
but what if I want to add a book? if it's title starts with 'A' I will have to update tens of millions of rows to set `alphabetically_sorted_title_number` for it
(add 1 to all books which must be listed after the new book)
the inserting performance drops drastically, is there a way to avoid this or speed this up? I've heard that PostgreSQL can do something with this, is it true?

Comment: If you really have hundreds of millions of rows, you might want to reconsider having those in a single table of a single instance ...

Comment: Eugen Rieck, is it a much better solution than anything else? How about oracle or postgre (as ppl down there suggest), can they really help somehow?

Comment: Monolithic RDBMS typically do not scale well by cost, once you hit 100s of millions of rows and thousands of queries per second.

Answer (score -1):

The best is change your bd to oracle or postgre(free option). The postgres have similar speed compared to oracle and is compatible to mysql.

If you insist in mysql, the best option is divide your search. Other problem is the "order by" in:

```
 SELECT * FROM `db_table` WHERE `alphabetically_sorted_title_number` > 20.000.000 ORDER BY `title` LIMIT 50
```

If the "title"  not is a index, its difficult your search and slow your result. 
try this:

```
Create index `index_title` ON `db_table`(col) ASC<br><br>
```

Repeat your query:

```
SELECT * FROM `db_table` WHERE `alphabetically_sorted_title_number` > 20.000.000 ORDER BY `title` LIMIT 50
```

Comment: The question states that title is indexed, therefore your code is useless here, what do you mean by dividing search? how can oracle/postgre help?